# How to tweak Erlang VM configurations?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, erlang-shell

I've read this [Link](http://soerlang.tumblr.com/post/35563581435/esl-mongooseim-vs-p1-ejabberd-part-i-piotr-nosek) on load testing eJabberd and MongooseIM. Author mentioned tweaking of Erlang VM [Link](http://soerlang.tumblr.com/post/35563581435/esl-mongooseim-vs-p1-ejabberd-part-i-piotr-nosek).

Tweaks:

```
+K true
+A 5
+P 10000000
-env ERL_MAX_PORTS 1000000
-env ERL_FULLSWEEP_AFTER 2
-env ERL_MAX_ETS_TABLES 100000
```

I tried using them like that `erl +K true` specified in this [Link](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html).

Questions: How to tweak Erlang VM? How does one check if the setting has been set? Do i need restart eJabberd after changing the settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read the man page. Some of those switches have changed and you don't give them as `-env` variables more in newer Erlang VM's. `ERL_MAX_PORTS` is the `+Q` switch now, for instance.

Also, do you need tuning at all? What is the problem you are trying to solve by tweaking knobs? Forcing a large amount of processes with the `+P` flag takes up lots of memory on older Erlang releases. So unless you use that many processes, it is a bad move.

And yes, emulator flags need a restart for them to be effective.

Comment: I'm load testing.I'm trying to figure out settings that will allow max amount of users for EC2.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong. I set the emulator flags, then start the eJabberd?

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do it. But I would not expect this to do too much unless you are running up against a limit. It is a shame you are not on raw metal, then the `+sbt` option is worth checking out.

Comment: For example `ERL_MAX_PORTS` is going in R18.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:
There is config file for eJabberd - `/etc/ejabberd/ejabberdctl.cfg` where you can specify all this settings specifically for eJabberd.
In this file you can configure options that are passed by ejabberdctl to the erlang runtime system when starting ejabberd